# SQL group by highest occurance

Tags: sql, group-by, count, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

By executing this query

```
SELECT year, genre, COUNT(genre)
FROM Oscar
GROUP BY year, genre
```

I got the following output:

```
2016        Action      2           
2016        Romance     1           
2017        Action      1           
2017        Romance     2           
2018        Fantasy     1           
2019        Action      1           
2019        Fantasy     2           
2020        Action      3           
2020        Fantasy     1           
2020        Romance     1
```

Now i want to display only the genre with the highest number per year to display. What is the best way to do this?

So I want the output to look like this:

```
2016 Action
2017 Romance
2018 Fantasy
2019 Fantasy
2020 Action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT year, genre
FROM (
    SELECT year, genre, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM Oscar
    GROUP BY year, genre
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

If your database does not support window functions (eg MySQL < 8.0), another option is:

```
SELECT year, genre
FROM Oscar o
GROUP BY year, genre
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Oscar o1 
    WHERE o1.year = o.year 
    GROUP BY o1.category 
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT year, genre
FROM (SELECT year, genre, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Oscar
      GROUP BY year, genre
     ) yg
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If there are ties, `RANK()` returns all highest ranked values.  Use `ROW_NUMBER()` if you specifically want one row, even when there are ties for first.